# Using %USERPROFILE% to Run External Script

Tags: vb.net

I am running an external script from a button on a VB.Net created GUI, which I can do but only when using the full path name to said script ("C:\Users\username\To scripts\myscript.vbs") but would like to use the %USERPROFILE% variable.

I've tried a number of things [which I've left in the script below], but unfortunately with no success, path errors etc, and therefore would be grateful for any assistance.

Many thanks

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim proc As New System.Diagnostics.Process()

        System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(
            "%USERPROFILE%")
        proc = Process.Start("%USERPROFILE%\To scripts\myscript.vbs", "")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetFolderPath()` and the `SpecialFolder` enumeration to find that file. To run a vbs file, you should call `cscript.exe` with given arguments.

```
Dim userProfile As String = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
Dim scriptFile As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(userProfile, "To scripts", "myscript.vbs")
Process.Start("cscript", $"//Nologo ""{scriptFile}""")
```

There is also an option like `//B` to run the script in batch mode (without UI).

---

Note that the double and triple quotes look fancy in the last code line but they are required if the `scriptFile` variable contains spaces. See (and run) [this interactive .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7XMoJf)

Comment: Many thanks, but unfortunately still getting the same error as previously "the system cannot find the file specified" . . . not sure whether its relevant, I’m using VS 2019.

Comment: My bad. It's "cscript" as process name and "//Nologo  ..." as argument in a second string. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks again, got it working but for some reason not with the last line, ran with no errors but the script did not run . . . reverted back, with mod, to proc = Process.Start(scriptFile, "") and the script ran.

Comment: Weascher . . . sorry for the delay but just some feedback.  Your script did work, however not with spaces in the path. i.e. changing "To scripts" to “Toscripts” worked.  I know its been some time but it you amend your script accordingly then I will tick as answered (don’t like leaving thing unresolved, and for other to review).

Comment: Thanks Richard, I did another update and added an interactive fiddle to see the behavior with and without the additional quotes.